# How to reference embedded chart?

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to assign the text in cells A1 and B1 to chart titles for

CHART1
CHART2

and

CHART3
CHART4

I am trying to loop through the workbook for the specific embedded chart which is located in random sheets.

I am getting

> "Member or data member not found"

on `With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Shapes(chtname).Chart`.

```
Sub ChartTitle()

    Dim chartNames As Variant
    
    For Each chtname In Array("CHART1", "CHART2")
        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Shapes(chtname).Chart
            .HasTitle = True
            .ChartTitle.Text = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Range("A1")
        End With
    Next

    For Each chtname In Array("CHART3", "CHART4")
        With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Shapes(chtname).Chart
            .HasTitle = True
            .ChartTitle.Text = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Range("B1")
        End With
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Aren't the charts embedded? Do you search for chart sheets?

Comment: `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Range("B1")` does  not have any meaning... Would you like to use a specific worksheet, or the sheet found during iteration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you do not answer my questions, please try the next code. Based on "*located in random sheets*", the code assumes that the charts in discussion are embedded ones. Since the code `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Range("B1")` does not have any meaning in VBA, the code allocate the values from the sheet where it is located:

```
Sub ModifyChartTitle()
    Dim sh As Worksheet, chObj As ChartObject

    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        For Each chObj In sh.ChartObjects
            If chObj.Chart.HasTitle Then
                Select Case chObj.Name
                     Case "CHART1", "CHART2"
                        chObj.Chart.ChartTitle.Text = sh.Range("A1").Value
                     Case "CHART3", "CHART4"
                        chObj.Chart.ChartTitle.Text = sh.Range("B1").Value
                End Select
            End If
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

If not embedded charts, or the chart Title must be collected from a specific worksheet, please better specify what is to be done...

Comment: Hi FaneDuru,

Sorry was without net. Exactly embedded charts! Flawless modification.
Thanks :)

Comment: @Kaizan: Glad I could help! I was preparing a second piece of code dealing with the chart sheets...